# Using like in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem in my project. I have table for saving category and I have a `listview` for viewing that category names and I have a text box above of the `listview`. When I type an alphabet in the `textbox`, I want to see the corresponding category name in the list view using LINQ query and for that I'm using this code:

```
 DataTable dt = (from c in Common.dc.TblBrands
                    where SqlMethods.Like(c.BrandName, txtSearch.Text+"%")
                    orderby c.BrandName
                    select c).getDataTable();
```

I can see the names correctly but I want to see the brand name when I input the brand id in the `textbox`. What query can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You may use [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx), or [StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx). For your particular case `SqlMethods.Like(c.BrandName, txtSearch.Text+"%")` you may use  `StartsWith`

```
DataTable dt = (from c in Common.dc.TblBrands
                where c.BrandName.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text)
                orderby c.BrandName
                select c).getDataTable();
```

Comment: bt here i can only search by brand name i want to search by brand id also thats the problem.

Comment: @user1793399, this will give you matching results on the basis of brand name, The result will contain the brand id as well, you have to figure out the way to display it in the listview.

Comment: @Habib: I think the OP is putting it badly, but he wants a query where the user input can match the brand name *or* the brand ID. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `SqlMethods.Like` available under namespace `System.Data.Linq.SqlClient`.

```
DataTable dt = (from c in Common.dc.TblBrands
                where SqlMethods.Like(c.BrandName, txtSearch.Text + "%")
                orderby c.BrandName
                select c).getDataTable();
```

**ADDED:** If you are trying to search on BrandId (assuming `int` type), you can do it this way:

```
DataTable dt = (from c in Common.dc.TblBrands
                where SqlMethods.Like(c.BrandName, txtSearch.Text + "%") ||
                      c.BrandId.ToString().Equals(txtSearch.Text)
                orderby c.BrandName
                select c).getDataTable();
```

Comment: DataTable dt = (from c in Common.dc.TblBrands
                where SqlMethods.Like(c.BrandName, txtSearch.Text + "%")||SqlMethods.Like(c.BrandId.getstring(), txtSearch.Text + "%")
                orderby c.BrandName
                select c).getDataTable(); can i use like this?

Comment: thats correct i agrre bt if i type the id of particular category in the text box at that time there load the brand name in the list view corresponding to that id.

Comment: ok now its working bt i want same time bran name search also thet meand if i enter id in text box der disply branname and if i enter brandname in the text box der will disply the brand name .

Comment: See my edited answer. It will search the brands both for BrandName and BrandId match.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
DataTable dt = (from c in Common.dc.TblBrands
                where SqlMethods.Like(c.BrandName, txtSearch.Text+"%")
                      || c.BrandId == txtSearch.Text
                orderby c.BrandName
                select c).getDataTable();
```

Or using `StartsWith` instead of `SqlMethods.Like`:

```
DataTable dt = (from c in Common.dc.TblBrands
                where c.BrandName.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text)
                      || c.BrandId == txtSearch.Text
                orderby c.BrandName
                select c).getDataTable();
```

This is all assuming `BrandId` is also a string, of course. If it's (say) an integer, it could get slightly hairier. In both cases I'd personally extract `txtSearch.Text` out first - and I doubt that I'd even have the query in code which had access to the UI, but that's an architectural matter.

(It's not clear what `getDataTable()` is here - if it's your own extension method, please consider fixing the name to follow .NET conventions.)